# Form: foreach inside a loop for

Tags: php, forms, loops, foreach

I'm using foreach and get some problem. I have 2 for loop with normally random value (for here I put fix value). I would like use foreach to take the value from the form

To explain better it the form looks like this:

```
Number 1 : T1 : ----
Number 2 : T2 : ---- and -----
So the user enter for example 2, 3, 4
So
Number 1 : T1 : 2
Number 2 : T2 : 3 and 4
```

The result I get is only 3 and 4. The value 2 is never save.
I think the problem is because the loop will start again the foreach so the value enter before will be delete. But I don't know how to do it.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post"> 
<?php 
for ($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++) {
    echo "Numero ";
    echo $i;
    for ($j = 1; $j <= 3; $j++) {
        echo $j;
        echo "<input type='text' name='number3[$j]' id='number3{$j}' />";
    }
}   
?>
<input type="submit" name="submitbutton" value="Confirm!">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitbutton'])) {

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++) {
    echo "Numero ";
    echo $i;
    for ($j = 1; $j <= 3; $j++) {
                echo "Lettre ";
                echo $j;
        foreach ($_POST['number3'] as $key => $value) {
            $_SESSION["number3_{$key}"] = $value;
            echo 'The value of $_SESSION['."'".$key."'".'] is '."'".$value."'".' <br />';
        }   

}   
}
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I do not quite understand what you're trying to accomplish, but you have problem in your code. This is html markup generated by your script:

```
<form action="/so.php" method="post"> 
Numero 1
1<input type='text' name='number3[1]' id='number31' />
2<input type='text' name='number3[2]' id='number32' />
3<input type='text' name='number3[3]' id='number33' />

Numero 2
1<input type='text' name='number3[1]' id='number31' />
2<input type='text' name='number3[2]' id='number32' />
3<input type='text' name='number3[3]' id='number33' />

<input type="submit" name="submitbutton" value="Confirm!">
</form>
```

As you see you the second set of inputs override the previous one, because you have the same names like `number3[1]`.

You should use multidimensional arrays to make your html look like

```
<input type='text' name='number3[1][1]' id='number31' />
```

And the iteration part in your script will be like

```
if (isset($_POST['submitbutton'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['number3'] as $firstKey => $insideArray) {
    echo "Numero ";
    echo $firstKey;
        foreach ($insideArray as $secondKey => $value) {
            $sessionKey = $firstKey . '_' . $secondKey;
            echo "Lettre ";
            echo $secondKey;
            $_SESSION[$sessionKey] = $value;
            echo 'The value of $_SESSION['.$sessionKey.'] is '."'".$value."'".' <br />';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: True, I didn't see this. Is it possible to do something like name='number3[$i][$j]' like this it will be different all the time?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: the problem I have now is the output is only "Array". no number anymore

Comment: yes it works! Thanks. I have one more question. I would like to use the data outside the loop foreach. The problem is the session start at 0 so if I use the data outside the foreach I always miss the first data.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know PHP allows you to post multi-dimensional variables. Your code would somehow look like this (I haven't tried it - so it is "only" a snippet).

Generation of the form (normally dynamic):

```
$numbers=2;
//note: $numbers is normally random (here 2 number records are generated)
for ($i = 1; $i <= $numbers; $i++) {
    echo "Number "+ $i + " <br/>";

    $fields=3;
    //note: $fields is normally random (here three fields per number are generated)
    for ($j = 1; $j <= $fields; $j++) {
        //this names the field by number[number_counter][field_counter]
        echo "<input type='text' label="+ $j +" name='number["+ $i +"]["+ $j +"]' />";
    }
}
```

Extraction of the posted form variables:

```
if (isset($_POST['submitbutton'])) {

    $current_number=1;
    foreach ($_POST['number'] as $number)
    {
        echo "Number " + $current_number +":<br/>";
        $field_counter = 1;
        foreach ($number as $field)
        {
            echo " The value of field #"+ $field_counter +"is "
              + $number[$field_counter] +".<br/>";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Btw. have a [look](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php) at something like `htmlspecialchars()`` to improve the security of the script ;-)